# If someone fixes "mPDF deprecated constructor issue" please share the mpdf library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

If someone fixes "the mPDF has a deprecated constructor issue" please share the mpdf library.

Screenshot:

[image]

Controller:

```
$data = [];
$html=$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data, true);

//this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
$pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";

//load mPDF library
$this->load->library('m_pdf');

//generate the PDF from the given html
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

//download it.
$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used mdf in my CodeIgniter projects and I am not using any third party libraries for it.You can easily install latest version of mpdf by using composer in codeigniter. This is how I implemented composer in CodeIgniter 3.It is very easy. You have to install composer on your machine download it from https://getcomposer.org/. After installing composer in your pc,

Copy and paste composer.json file in the project folder to application folder.
In the config.php file $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
Now you have composer in your project. Now i will saw you how to install mpdf using composer

Open cmd and direct to projectname/application.
Inside application directory Type composer require mpdf/mpdf
Now a vendor folder will be created inside application folder and inside vendor folder you can see all your packages downloaded by composer.

Now since you autoloaded composer now you can just use the code given by mpdf official manual like in your controllers.

```
    function m_pdf(){ 

       $mpdf = new mPDF();

       // Write some HTML code:

       $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

       // Output a PDF file directly to the browser
       $mpdf->Output();
   }
```

Remember you don't need to type require_once APPPATH.'/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php'; since you already autoloader composer. If not prefer to autoload composer you must type require_once APPPATH.'/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php' at the beginning of each controllers where you use the mpdf vendor libraries. If you encountered any problems please comment below.

Comment: I thank you (@Geordy James) for your answer. It's working correctly